# Is there a way to check if the transactions are happening on binance smart chain network or ethereum smart chain?

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity, binance-smart-chain, binance-chain

I'm new to block chain development and developing a DApp on binance smart chain. I changed the network from default ethereum web provider to binance test network provider. DApp is working fine but I want the affirmation that my transaction are happening on binance test network. Is there a way to check if the transaction is happening on binance smart chain network or ethereum network? Thanks a ton

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Web3 connection has a method that allows you to ask `chainId` of the currently connected blockchain.

[See Chainlist for full details](https://chainlist.org/).